# Ordenar los colores en base a el arcoiris con quicksort

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos, ordenamiento

Hola tengo un problema que estoy tratando de resolver pero me confundí el problema es que tengo que ordenar los colores por la posición del arcoiris (rojo, naranja, amarillo, verde, índigo, violeta y azul) luego tengo que ordenarlo con un valor de gradiente y tiene que ser con el algoritmo quicksort, ya tengo el algoritmo de ordenación la entrada es el número de n colores que los colores con el número de gradiente ordena todo pero solo por orden alfabético y no en el arcoiris.

Este sería la entrada:

4 Rojo-66 Rojo-1 verde-13 Azul-33

pero mi programa hace:

Azul-33 Rojo-1 Rojo-66 verde-13

cuando debería ser:

Rojo-1 Rojo-66 Verde-13 Azul-33

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Cualquier ayuda sería genial

¿Cómo es que puedo separar los números para poder ordenarlos por su número que lo acompaña?

Y ¿Cómo es que puedo ordenar los números que le acompañan con quicksort?

```
arcoiris = ['Rojo', 'Anaranjado', 'Amarillo', 'Verde', 'Indigo', 'Violeta', 'Azul']

lst = []

n = int(input("n = "))
lst = [input("> ") for _ in range(n)]




class MySort:
    def display(self, arr, size):
        i = 0
        while (i < size):
            print(" ", arr[i], end="")
            i += 1

        print("\n", end="")

    def swap(self, arr, first, second):
        temp = arr[first]
        arr[first] = arr[second]
        arr[second] = temp

    def part(self, arr, low, high):
        pv = arr[high]
        i = low - 1
        j = low
        while (j < high):
            if (arr[j] < pv):
                i += 1
                self.swap(arr, i, j)

            j += 1

        self.swap(arr, i + 1, high)
        return i + 1

    def quick_sort(self, arr, low, high):
        if (low < high):
            pv = self.part(arr, low, high)
            self.quick_sort(arr, low, pv - 1)
            self.quick_sort(arr, pv + 1, high)


def main():
    obj = MySort()
    arr = lst
    size = len(arr)
    obj.display(arr, size)
    obj.quick_sort(arr, 0, size - 1)
    obj.display(arr, size)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución al problema es inventar una llave que te sirva. En este caso, usare una llave compuesta de frecuencia más gradiente.

La frecuencia es un entero que representa la posición en el arcoiris. La frecuencia de Rojo es 0, Anaranjado es 1, etc.

La gradiente es un valor entre 0 y 100 (supongo).

El proceso es pedir el par color-gradiente, separarlo en sus partes, buscar el color dentro del arcoiris y luego calcular el valor de orden como `frecuencia * 100 + gradiente`. Multiplico la frecuencia por 100 para poder agregar a la cola el valor de la gradiente, sin confundir ambos.

```
n = int(input("n = "))
for _ in range(n):
    color_gradiente = input(">")
    color, gradiente = color_gradiente.split("-")
    gradiente = int(gradiente)
    frecuencia = arcoiris.index(color.lower())
    valor = frecuencia * 100 + gradiente
    lst.append((valor, color_gradiente))
```

En la lista guardara tuplas con:

- El valor de frecuencia * gradiente.
- El color-gradiente ingresado

#### Demo

```
arcoiris = ['rojo', 'anaranjado', 'amarillo', 'verde', 'indigo', 'violeta', 'azul']

lst = []

n = int(input("n = "))
for _ in range(n):
    color_gradiente = input(">")
    color, gradiente = color_gradiente.split("-")
    gradiente = int(gradiente)
    frecuencia = arcoiris.index(color.lower())
    valor = frecuencia * 100 + gradiente
    lst.append((valor, color_gradiente))

class MySort:
    def display(self, arr, size):
        i = 0
        while (i < size):
            print(" ", arr[i], end="")
            i += 1

        print("\n", end="")

    def swap(self, arr, first, second):
        temp = arr[first]
        arr[first] = arr[second]
        arr[second] = temp

    def part(self, arr, low, high):
        pv = arr[high]
        i = low - 1
        j = low
        while (j < high):
            if (arr[j] < pv):
                i += 1
                self.swap(arr, i, j)

            j += 1

        self.swap(arr, i + 1, high)
        return i + 1

    def quick_sort(self, arr, low, high):
        if (low < high):
            pv = self.part(arr, low, high)
            self.quick_sort(arr, low, pv - 1)
            self.quick_sort(arr, pv + 1, high)


def main():
    obj = MySort()
    arr = lst
    size = len(arr)
    obj.display(arr, size)
    obj.quick_sort(arr, 0, size - 1)
    obj.display(arr, size)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

produce:

```
n = 4
>Rojo-66
>Rojo-1 
>verde-13
>Azul-33
  (66, 'Rojo-66')  (1, 'Rojo-1 ')  (313, 'verde-13')  (633, 'Azul-33')
  (1, 'Rojo-1 ')  (66, 'Rojo-66')  (313, 'verde-13')  (633, 'Azul-33')

Process finished with exit code 0
```